# Resaving a simple product generated from configurable product in Magento2 for Layered navigation to update?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

Not sure if it's a bug or I'm just missing the point but when I create a configurable product in Magento 2.2.1 - the layered navigation on the front end doesn't update.

To get the layered navigation to be updated, I have to resave any one, yes only one, of the simple products that were generated when creating the configurable product.

So I guess my question is...

**Why do I need to resave a simple product that's been generated from creating a configurable product in Magento 2.2.1 for changes to be applied to the Layered navigation on the frontend?**